# Is it possible to make a torn paper effect on edges of a picture?

Tags: html, css, image, photoshop

**Update 3**

I updated the [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYRJLp) (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYRJLp) and now the edges look really like torn paper effect. It uses SVG by the way.

The only problem is I don't know how to make the image as the background of the svg AT THE SAME TIME maintain the torn-paper-like edges.

Please have a look it. Any efforts are appreciated.

---

**Update 2**

It seems that it is impossible to achieve this effect without the help of PhotoShop(PS), so I would like to add PS as a part of solution.

I am not a PS expert, but from a quick thought, I think there are a few steps I need to do:

- Use PS to create a torn paper "shell", let's say it's shell.png It
  should only have color on its edges and the color should be white;
  the inner area is transparent, so that we can place the picture in
  it.
- Place shell.png on top of the picture, let's say banner.jpg, which
  means set the z-index of the div which uses shell as its background
  image to 1.
- Use another div to contain the banner.jpg and set the z-index below
  the shell div.

**Questions for this approach:**

- Is it responsive?
- If not, is it possible to make it responsive? As I have to make it
  work properly on mobile devices.

---

I remember that I saw a beautifully designed website, there is a picture in the background and the edges of this picture look like torn paper effect which is fantastic!

I searched the similar questions here but it turns out that the effects in the answers are primitive, which are very simple rugged black lines.

What I want:

1. I want this picture to be as wide as the device screen which means
   responsive.
2. The edges of this picture look like torn paper.
3. I will place this picture as a banner after the Top Navigation bar
   but before the content.

It should look like the white area in this picture. But in my case, I will need to fill in my picture to replace the white area.

[image]

Here is my code:
Notice: in this code, the css uses an image as the edge, BUT that is not want I want. I just want the edges to be pure CSS effects.(Is this possible?) So it will look like this one(the one on the right side, you can see that there is no white rugged edges)
[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="letter" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    </div>
</div>

#letter { /*torn paper border*/
    height:450px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-image:url('img/background.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    opacity:0.8;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 40px 40px 40px; 
       -moz-border-image: url('http://news.unchealthcare.org/images/backgrounds/paper.jpg') 80 80 80 repeat; 
    -webkit-border-image: url('http://news.unchealthcare.org/images/backgrounds/paper.jpg') 80 80 80 repeat; 
         -o-border-image: url('http://news.unchealthcare.org/images/backgrounds/paper.jpg') 80 80 80 repeat; 
            border-image: url('http://news.unchealthcare.org/images/backgrounds/paper.jpg') 80 80 80 repeat;
}
```

---

**Update**

I think I found something quite similar to what I am imagine.
Here is the effect I want:
[image]

Comment: maybe this pen can help http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/yyaGWx

Comment: hi @web-tiki  thank you for your help, but it looks more like erosion rather the edges of torn paper.

Comment: hi @web-tiki I looked at the effect again and found that it is really close to the effect I want. Only one thing ruins the whole effect which is all torn edges end very clearly at a line. So if somehow we could remove that line, then it will look really like a torn paper effect. Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: hi @web-tiki I use the pen you provided and tweaked and now it looks really similar to the torn paper. Please have a look the Update 3. Thanks

Comment: @Franva please give the link again (and even better, copy/paste the relevant part of the code in an answer)

Comment: hi @oliverpool where link are you talking about? If you mean the fantastic website which has torn paper effect that I saw many years ago, I cannot find it. All I remember is that is a website about Thailand Floating Market, there is a photo in the middle of the website. On the top edge of the photo it has torn paper effect, but the div below the bottom edge has the same color which makes the perfect match. And that's why I say it's fantastic and still remember it so clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Update 3 of the pen.

Comment: hi @oliverpool it's in my update 3, but here it is again : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYRJLp  :)

Comment: [Pure CSS version without background image.](https://codepen.io/Dzmitry-Lahoda/pen/qPEKLg)

Comment: thanks @DzmitryLahoda

Answer (score 20):

I was able to do this with CSS using border image slicing.

Here's the code:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/jdRfmPxv/1-2-OKX1nhs-Z3-CB2-Cid-Edh-Jw.png");
}
.border {
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/DZYqPDTD/bordernew.png) 50 0 50 0 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/DZYqPDTD/bordernew.png) 50 0 50 0 repeat;
  -moz-border-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/DZYqPDTD/bordernew.png) 50 0 50 0 repeat;
  border-image-slice: 50 0 50 0 fill;
  border-image-width: 20 0 20 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
.p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="border" style="text-align:center;">
  <br />
  <span class="p">Coming soon...</span>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

This gives me a height re-sizing div that always has the torn paper effect along the top and bottom. It's great for full width, but I wasn't able to figure out a decent way of doing the side edges at the same time as the top and bottom (easy to do the side edges if the top and bottom edges are straight).

I made the image in Photoshop - it's basically yellow in the middle, then torn and then transparent on the outer.

If you're not familiar with image slicing, the four numbers basically define (in order): the height in pixels of the top of the image that you want to use as the top border strip, the width in pixels for the right strip, then the bottom strip, then the left strip. The `fill` tells it to take the center part (which is discarded by default) and use it to fill the div between the borders.

Depending on your preferences you can have the border `repeat` (and get cut off at the end), `round` (repeat to the nearest number of full repetitions, which either compresses or stretches depending on which number it is nearer to) or `stretch` (stretches... although that distorts the image for this example).

It took some fiddling for me to get it to work correctly but I'm chuffed with the results. I couldn't find anyone with the same answer so thought I'd post it.

**UPDATE**

This feature IS supported in IE11 provided `border-style:solid` is specified. I use media queries to provide an alternative (shadows etc.) for IE10 and below where `border-image` is not supported (example on my website).

**UPDATE 04/2020**

It's now 2020 and it's been a few years since my original answer (I've learned a lot in 5 years). I recently did this on another project for [wooden watches](https://ecorelos.com) and stuff using a simpler method. I find the div I want to apply the border to and use either `:before` or `:after` to add the border as below. Again, the image I made in Photoshop but this time it's white > torn edge > transparent rather than coloured.

To add to the bottom:

```
.targetdivclass:after{
     content:" ";
     display:block;
     height: 45px;
     background-image:url('https://ecorelos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/torn-border2.png');
     position:absolute;
     bottom:-15px;
    width:300%;
left:-500px;    
}
```

To add to the top (note that you need a flipped version of the image unless you want to transform/rotate it in CSS as well):

```
    .targetdivclass:before{
        content:" ";
     display:block;
     width:300%;
     height: 65px;
     background-image:url('https://ecorelos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/torn-border2upside.png');
     position:absolute;
     margin-top:-80px;
     left:-500px;
       z-index:1;
}
```

Adjust the `height`, `bottom`, `width` and `left` to suit the image and the website. Note that if you apply this to the footer you can cause issues having a width greater than 100%, in which case you need to keep the `left` at zero.

This is responsive, but you can use media queries to specify different sizes and margins for mobile if necessary.

The result is the same effect that was originally requested:

[image]

Comment: That's correct - I'm using it as a 'coming soon' website and that's the text I put. The images aren't hosted online yet so they're not showing, I'll put them online later so you can see (I can't at the moment). I didn't know about the 'run code snippet' feature when I posted the code, sorry!

Comment: Images added so the snippet works now :) but not in IE still

Comment: I notice the effect I have is the opposite to what you wanted - I have the photo being torn to reveal the background, and you want the photo to have torn edges on top of the background. This is fairly easy to reverse by  swapping the top and bottom edges of your border image file, so the shadows fall on the outside rather than the inside, and the inside is transparent instead of a solid colour like mine. Hopefully this will all be of some help.

Comment: hi Lyall, your last comment seems is what I want, could you please update your code to demonstrate what you mentioned in the comment? Also, I found it's confusing to find out where the torn edges are when viewing the repeated images, could you please make only one image surrounded by torn edges? thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
clip-path: polygon(3% 0, 7% 1%, 11% 0%, 16% 2%, 20% 0, 23% 2%, 28% 2%, 32% 1%, 35% 1%, 39% 3%, 41% 1%, 45% 0%, 47% 2%, 50% 2%, 53% 0, 58% 2%, 60% 2%, 63% 1%, 65% 0%, 67% 2%, 69% 2%, 73% 1%, 76% 1%, 79% 0, 82% 1%, 85% 0, 87% 1%, 89% 0, 92% 1%, 96% 0, 98% 3%, 99% 3%, 99% 6%, 100% 11%, 98% 15%, 100% 21%, 99% 28%, 100% 32%, 99% 35%, 99% 40%, 100% 43%, 99% 48%, 100% 53%, 100% 57%, 99% 60%, 100% 64%, 100% 68%, 99% 72%, 100% 75%, 100% 79%, 99% 83%, 100% 86%, 100% 90%, 99% 94%, 99% 98%, 95% 99%, 92% 99%, 89% 100%, 86% 99%, 83% 100%, 77% 99%, 72% 100%, 66% 98%, 62% 100%, 59% 99%, 54% 99%, 49% 100%, 46% 98%, 43% 100%, 40% 98%, 38% 100%, 35% 99%, 31% 100%, 28% 99%, 25% 99%, 22% 100%, 19% 99%, 16% 100%, 13% 99%, 10% 99%, 7% 100%, 4% 99%, 2% 97%, 1% 97%, 0% 94%, 1% 89%, 0% 84%, 1% 81%, 0 76%, 0 71%, 1% 66%, 0% 64%, 0% 61%, 0% 59%, 1% 54%, 0% 49%, 1% 45%, 0% 40%, 1% 37%, 0% 34%, 1% 29%, 0% 23%, 2% 20%, 1% 17%, 1% 13%, 0 10%, 1% 6%, 1% 3%);
```

Comment: Sadly this becomes a tad more difficult once you realize that Edge (of course) doesn't support this and that you must clip-path inside an svg to make it work.

Answer (score 8):

I used some pen I found to come up with my own solution that has rips on all four sides. You can change it to have rips on only the top, bottom, left, right, or any combination thereof.

The key ingredients:

1. Use `clip-path: polygon(…)` to "cut" the object you want to have the rip effect.
2. Use `filter: drop-shadow(…)` on the container to give the thing a shadow.

Not only does this give a shadow, but that shadow **follows the pattern of the rip** so that it looks more realistic.

Live action:

https://codepen.io/carterpape/pen/rNjJKbM

Comment: Gosh after 6 years, still this question gets a lot of loves~! Amazing ! :) I checked our your solution, the effect looks great~! thanks for sharing this!

Comment: how did you generate those long paths? you can't manually type it, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve this effect with a png image.

The top part should be black (or whatever the color of your header), the bottom is partly transparent to create the "torn effect", and your real image will be on a lower layer (z-index) to be partly hidden.

**Reply to Update2** *this is what I meant*

Instead of creating a complete shell (a "square" hole), you can split the four edges in four images: top, right, bottom and left.

You can make it responsive by simply repeating the image on the whole length (the "start" and "end" of the four edges must be the same)
*

Comment: Thanks Oliver, could you please provide a demo?

Comment: hi @web-tiki I use the pen you provided and tweaked and now it looks really similar to the torn paper. Please have a look the Update 3. Thanks