# How to get a torn paper effect with random saw teeth?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I am trying to make a torn paper effect like the image below:

[image]

with the torn effect on the bottom side. **[I saw this](http://css-shapes.xyz/saw-tooth-border-effect)** and was able to make a torn paper effect as shown below

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: darkred;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  background: darkred;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 15px -15px 0 0 darkred, 30px -30px 0 0 darkred, 45px -45px 0 0 darkred, 60px -60px 0 0 darkred, 75px -75px 0 0 darkred, 90px -90px 0 0 darkred, 105px -105px 0 0 darkred, 120px -120px 0 0 darkred, 135px -135px 0 0 darkred, 150px -150px 0 0 darkred, 165px -165px 0 0 darkred, 180px -180px 0 0 darkred, 195px -195px 0 0 darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

But the problem is that the torn edges look alike. I want them to be in different sizes with different shapes.

Comment: If you prefer a more 'realistic' look you can use a custom PNG image and border image slicing such as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349151/is-it-possible-to-make-a-torn-paper-effect-on-edges-of-a-picture/31392023#31392023 just use an image with the effect on the right edge instead of top and bottom as per the example in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31392023/4952851.

Comment: People need to quit pretending CSS is a drawing program.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This can be done using svg. I am using Snap and jquery to make it as it makes everything a lot easier.

The following snippets create random torn paper effects.

> Note:Support for snap - IE9 and up, Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera [see the specs](http://snapsvg.io/about/)
>
> Support for svg [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = Snap('svg');
  var width = $('.content').outerWidth();
  $('.effect').width(width);
  var lastX = 0;
  var pointsArray = [0, 0];
  while (lastX <= width) {
    var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);
    var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
    pointsArray.push(randX + lastX + ' ' + randY);
    lastX = lastX + randX;
  }
  var torn = s.polygon(pointsArray + " " + width + " 0").attr({
    fill: 'orange'
  })
})
```

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px;
}
.effect {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="torn">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="effect">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

How this works ?

First an array is created to hold the coordinates that are randomly created by jquery. x and y coordinates are created using `Math.random()` and are added to the array.Before adding to the array the current x coordinate is added to the last x coordinate received. This is to make it continuous.

Changing the `10` in the `randX` variable allows us to increase or decrease the length of one line and changing the `30` in the `randY` variable allows to change the height of one line.

Here is a snippet that uses low `randX`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = Snap('svg');
  var width = $('.content').outerWidth();
  $('.effect').width(width);
  var lastX = 0;
  var lastY = 0;
  var pointsArray = [0, 0];
  while (lastX <= width) {
    var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
    pointsArray.push(randX + lastX + ' ' + randY);
    lastX = lastX + randX;
  }
  var torn = s.polygon(pointsArray + " " + width + " 0").attr({
    fill: 'orange'
  })
})
```

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px;
}
.effect {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="torn">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="effect">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would like to have one with border?

Change `polygon` to `polyline` and add `stroke`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = Snap('svg');
  var width = $('.content').outerWidth();
  $('.effect').width(width);
  var lastX = 0;
  var lastY = 0;
  var pointsArray = [0, 0];
  while (lastX <= width) {
    var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
    pointsArray.push(randX + lastX + ' ' + randY);
    lastX = lastX + randX;
  }
  var torn = s.polyline(pointsArray + " " + (width - 3) + " 0").attr({
    fill: 'orange',
    'stroke': 'black',
    'stroke-width': 3
  })
})
```

```css
.torn {
  margin: 50px;
}
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.effect {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="torn">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="effect">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't like random torn effects ?

i would suggest picking a nice torn effect from the random ones and copying its html like i have did here

```css
.torn {
  margin: 50px;
}
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px;
}
.effect {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="torn">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="effect" style="width: 440px;">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
      <desc>Created with Snap</desc>
      <defs></defs>
      <polygon points="0,0,10 25,20 15,27 21,43 24,51 14,70 9,84 25,88 18,96 11,100 20,113 6,117 5,123 1,136 25,151 29,157 4,166 29,181 2,197 28,212 8,226 8,232 12,240 8,254 16,270 5,279 26,291 5,304 0,307 5,325 26,329 18,347 3,360 5,372 26,382 9,393 21,406 27,411 8,415 4,429 8,441 19 437 0"
      fill="#ffa500"></polygon>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need background images ?

Add an image using snap, set it's y coordinates to -440 (ie,height of the content.400 if padding is avoided) and clip it using the polygon

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = Snap('svg');
  var width = $('.content').outerWidth();
  $('.effect').width(width);
  var lastX = 0;
  var lastY = 0;
  var pointsArray = [0, 0];
  while (lastX <= width) {
    var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30);
    pointsArray.push(randX + lastX + ' ' + randY);
    lastX = lastX + randX;
  }
  var img = s.image('https://placeimg.com/440/500/any', 0, -440, 440, 500)
  var torn = s.polygon(pointsArray + " " + (width - 3) + " 0").attr({

  })
  img.attr({
    'clip-path': torn
  })
})
```

```css
.torn {
  margin: 50px;
}
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px;
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/440/500/any');
}
.effect {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="torn">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="effect">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code for generating the random points has a bug: it can overflow. If `lastX` is very close to `width`, then adding `lastX + randX` can get bigger than `width`. You can see this effect very good in the border example.

Comment: I noticed that @r0estir0bbe but as it overflow it looks like it is a part of the cutting effect so i didn't do anything for that

Comment: @machineyearning: I would definitely agree that Akshay's answer looks much better but just to let you know the first 3 snippets in my answer have fixed points which were arbitrarily added. The final one would produce the exact output as in Akshay's answer when the array generation logic is tuned to be exactly same as Akshay's. It's just a matter of array generation.

Comment: @Harry good point, in fact I did some playing around on my own and found what seemed like even way better-looking solutions. Seems like more points looks for the most part more realistic.

Comment: @machineyearning: Yep, the key is in the array that is generated. The more the length of the array the better it looks :) But I'd definitely say Akshay's SVG answer is the better one as of now because one cannot use the `clip-path` solution in a production ready site due to the browser support. My answer is more in hope that one day `clip-path` would have better support.

Comment: I agree with r0estir0bbe that when the border effect is in place, the lower right of the image has a break in the border that looks bad. This could easily be fixed with a little `if` statement somewhere limiting the last step to land exactly at the width.

Comment: The question asked for this to be done in HTML and CSS.

Comment: Nope @Rob It is tagged svg too

Comment: Yes but you're using javascript which is not asked for, however, I learned it was in the original question.

Comment: @Rob Yes it was tagged with `jquery` at first later it was edited by someone and replaced it with css3

Comment: This is nice! One recommendation: Try using gaussian blur with very small radius! Oh I just saw it wasnt asked in the question

Answer (score 42):

**Using Clip Paths:**

The torn paper effect can also produced using `clip-path` It can be done with only HTML and CSS but the pure CSS version wouldn't produce a random clip effect like we can achieve using SNAP or other SVG libraries but it does produce a torn paper effect.

The **drawback** of using CSS `clip-path` is that it is **currently supported only in Webkit powered browsers**. Firefox supports only the `url()` syntax and so needs inline SVGs while it has absolutely no support in IE. [[Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)]

```css
.torn-paper{
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: tomato;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 97%, 2% 95%, 6% 99%, 12% 88%, 18% 92%, 27% 90%, 31% 97%, 39% 91%, 47% 95%, 60% 83%, 62% 81%, 69% 93%, 72% 96%, 79% 87%, 100% 99%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 97%, 2% 95%, 6% 99%, 12% 88%, 18% 92%, 27% 90%, 31% 97%, 39% 91%, 47% 95%, 60% 83%, 62% 81%, 69% 93%, 72% 96%, 79% 87%, 100% 99%, 100% 0%);  
}
```

```html
<div class='torn-paper'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

As the `clip-path` is percentage based, it is by default responsive and it can work when the container `div` has a background image also.

```css
.torn-paper{
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 97%, 2% 95%, 6% 99%, 12% 88%, 18% 92%, 27% 90%, 31% 97%, 39% 91%, 47% 95%, 60% 83%, 62% 81%, 69% 93%, 72% 96%, 79% 87%, 100% 99%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 97%, 2% 95%, 6% 99%, 12% 88%, 18% 92%, 27% 90%, 31% 97%, 39% 91%, 47% 95%, 60% 83%, 62% 81%, 69% 93%, 72% 96%, 79% 87%, 100% 99%, 100% 0%);  
}
```

```html
<div class='torn-paper'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

If we really want a random torn paper effect then we can set the co-ordinates of the `polygon` clip path using JS and then add it as an inline style like in the below snippet. The snippet uses a logic similar to that in your answer to populate the array.

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('torn-paper')[0];

var lastX = 0,
  randX, randY, polygonPoints = ["0% 0%"];

randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 80;

polygonPoints.push(lastX + '% ' + randY + '%');

while (lastX <= 100) {
  randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 85;
  polygonPoints.push(randX + lastX + '% ' + randY + '%');
  lastX = lastX + randX;
}
polygonPoints.push("100% 0%");

el.style['-webkit-clip-path'] = 'polygon(' + polygonPoints.join() + ')';
el.style['clip-path'] = 'polygon(' + polygonPoints.join() + ')';
```

```css
.torn-paper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
0
<div class='torn-paper'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

I hadn't made the following as my primary answer because SVGs were already covered in a different way in Akshay's answer but using inline SVG for the `clip-path` **would work in Firefox also**. IE still won't support it.

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('torn-paper')[0];
var path = document.getElementById('clipper-path');

var lastX = 0,
  randX, randY, polygonPoints = ["0 0"];

randY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 80) / 100;

polygonPoints.push(lastX + ' ' + randY + '');

while (lastX <= 1) {
  randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) / 100;
  randY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 85) / 100;
  polygonPoints.push(randX + lastX + ' ' + randY + '');
  lastX = lastX + randX;
}
polygonPoints.push("1 0");

path.setAttribute('d', 'M' + polygonPoints.join() + 'z');
```

```css
.torn-paper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: tomato;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipper);
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d='M0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1z' id='clipper-path' />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="torn-paper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

---

**Using Canvas:**

I know that you haven't tagged Canvas but if you are looking for support in IE also then using Canvas would also be a good option. Canvas has very good browser support (same as SVG). I am including it here just as another option that could be used.

The approach is very much the same as explained earlier because here also we are creating a path and then clipping the canvas based on the path.

The below snippets are **tested in IE9+, Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera**.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('torn-canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var lastX = 0,
  randX, randY;

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

randY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 85) / 100 * canvas.height;
ctx.lineTo(0, randY);

while (lastX <= canvas.width) {
  randX = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 7.5)) / 100 * canvas.width;
  randY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 85) / 100 * canvas.height;
  lastX = lastX + randX;
  ctx.lineTo(lastX, randY);
}
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'tomato';
ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}
#torn-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <canvas id='torn-canvas' height='300px' width='300px'></canvas>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
```

We can even add an image as the background by first drawing the image on to the Canvas and then clipping it to shape.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('torn-canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var lastX = 0,
  randX, randY, img = new Image();

ctx.save();
img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/300/nature/4';
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
ctx.restore();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

randY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 85) / 100 * canvas.height;
ctx.lineTo(0, randY);

while (lastX <= canvas.width) {
  randX = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) / 100 * canvas.width;
  randY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 85) / 100 * canvas.height;
  lastX = lastX + randX;
  ctx.lineTo(lastX, randY);
}
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.restore();
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  color: white;
}
#torn-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <canvas id='torn-canvas' height='300px' width='300px'></canvas>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
```

Comment: Probably downvoted because it's not as portable as the other answer.

Comment: Well the other one works in IE and Firefox. Nothing wrong with adding the answer, just don't get salty if it's downvoted because it doesn't work.

Comment: I've already added a version which works in Firefox also. I am not getting salty but I find it ridiculous that people downvote an answer just because the technology is not as popularly supported right now. I can understand if you (not exactly you) choose not to vote but to downvote an answer which answers the question which states no browser constraints is downright ridiculous.

Comment: Didn't know there were others who hated coding purely for WebKit with a greater passion than I did (apparently I don't hate it enough to downvote this answer, but do enough to downvote obvious things like using only -webkit- prefixes in CSS).

Comment: Now that I'd definitely understand @BoltClock. Hoping for the next IE version to provide atleast basic clip path support. Coming to the down votes, I should probably acknowledge the fact that <= 10% people in any group will always have views different from the rest :)

Comment: Since the question asked for this to be done in HTML and CSS, why are you using javscript?

Comment: @Rob: (1) The question originally had jQuery tagged which was removed by some user. (2) Random torn effect is not possible using CSS alone. If you see the first part of my answer there is a pure CSS version which doesn't produce random cuts (3) The OP has self answered the question and they've used JS/jQuery in their answer also which leads me to believe that they are fine with some JS/jQuery to achieve randomness.

Answer (score 5):

I am sure this post is likely dead, but I am leaving this comment here in case anyone finds it helpful. I created a jagged effect with the following CSS:

```
clip-path: polygon(3% 0, 7% 1%, 11% 0%, 16% 2%, 20% 0, 23% 2%, 28% 2%, 32% 1%, 35% 1%, 39% 3%, 41% 1%, 45% 0%, 47% 2%, 50% 2%, 53% 0, 58% 2%, 60% 2%, 63% 1%, 65% 0%, 67% 2%, 69% 2%, 73% 1%, 76% 1%, 79% 0, 82% 1%, 85% 0, 87% 1%, 89% 0, 92% 1%, 96% 0, 98% 3%, 99% 3%, 99% 6%, 100% 11%, 98% 15%, 100% 21%, 99% 28%, 100% 32%, 99% 35%, 99% 40%, 100% 43%, 99% 48%, 100% 53%, 100% 57%, 99% 60%, 100% 64%, 100% 68%, 99% 72%, 100% 75%, 100% 79%, 99% 83%, 100% 86%, 100% 90%, 99% 94%, 99% 98%, 95% 99%, 92% 99%, 89% 100%, 86% 99%, 83% 100%, 77% 99%, 72% 100%, 66% 98%, 62% 100%, 59% 99%, 54% 99%, 49% 100%, 46% 98%, 43% 100%, 40% 98%, 38% 100%, 35% 99%, 31% 100%, 28% 99%, 25% 99%, 22% 100%, 19% 99%, 16% 100%, 13% 99%, 10% 99%, 7% 100%, 4% 99%, 2% 97%, 1% 97%, 0% 94%, 1% 89%, 0% 84%, 1% 81%, 0 76%, 0 71%, 1% 66%, 0% 64%, 0% 61%, 0% 59%, 1% 54%, 0% 49%, 1% 45%, 0% 40%, 1% 37%, 0% 34%, 1% 29%, 0% 23%, 2% 20%, 1% 17%, 1% 13%, 0 10%, 1% 6%, 1% 3%);
```

Now, I am sure this can be refined further to give a more convincing look, but I think this is a great way to give a rough shape to an image area.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) pages for how to write good questions and answers. Your answer doesn't address the random part of the question. I.e. the paper will be "torn" the same way for each element. Note the accepted answer uses a random function in the code.

Comment: @CJDennis - I believe OP meant seemingly "random" as opposed to actually randomized. OP wanted a variety of saw teeth depths as opposed to all teeth being even like an actual saw, as described: "I want them to be in different sizes with different shapes." That's what is meant by "random" and can be accomplished without actual randomization. This CSS only solution is great!